# How do I get the data from HostedFeatureLayer for today's date using Python from ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api

Currently, I am pulling all the data from the `featurelayerid` using the below script:

```
feature_layer_id = ' '
Inspform = gis.content.get(feature_layer_id) 
insp=Inspform.layers[0].query().sdf
insp.to_sql('testtable',con=engine,schema=None,if_exists='replace',index=False,index_label=None,dtype=None,method=None)
```

The featurelayer has two fields with create date and edit date. Would like to pull data where create date or edit date is equal to sysdate.

How can I achieve this? I am new to Python and ArcGIS

I browsed some sample notebooks, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a where clause in line 3, something like:

```py
insp=Inspform.layers[0].query(where="OBJECTID=1").sdf
```

Comment: Thank You, I am not able to make the syntax work for dates. The Createdate and edit date are defined as datetime

Comment: insp=Inspform.layers[0].query(where =" CreationDate > [datetime(2022, 10, 7)]").sdf ;  I am trying  to figure out the correct syntax